# Datetime format in java for date like 'Jun 3, 2020 5:04:05 PM'

Tags: java, date, datetime

Is there an format in java for parsing date such as 'Jun 3, 2020 5:04:05 PM' because i'm creating an app in JEE and i got ths message  in my log file when persisting data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)) instead of using the outdated `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about the modern date/time API.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.US);

        // Date/time string
        String strDate = "Jun 3, 2020 5:04:05 PM";

        // Parse the date/time string into LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);

        // Display ldt.toString()
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Display `ldt` in the specified format
        System.out.println(formatter.format(ldt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-03T17:04:05
Jun 3, 2020 5:04:05 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
String dString =  "Jun 3, 2020 5:04:05 PM" 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
Date date = formater.parse(dString);
```

EDIT:
Dealing with locale:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa", Locale.US)
```

You can also look at `LocalDateTime` and  `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: _yes that's it_

Comment: Do not forget to take Local's into account depending on your situation it can cause errors

Comment: _The problem is really when i want to persist data from android application to JEE glassfish server in mysql now i'm getting that problem. thanks in advance_

Comment: _Ok i will try to take into account Local's date, may it will solve my case thank you_

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.